# Instantiating New Object Instance for LInq to Sql Insertion

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm starting to learn Linq (and loving it by the way).  But I'm struggling to perform a simple insertion of a single record.  Below is how I think it should go.  My problem is that I cannot instantiate a new instance of Address.  Intellisense doesn't recognize Address.  I can query Address fine by performing a simple select.  Similarly I've had no problems using Linq to delete records from the Address table.  I'm probably overlooking something pretty basic.  Any ideas?

```
protected void InsertAddress()
{

    using (SBMData2.SBMDataContext db = new SBMData2.SBMDataContext())
    {
       //Create a new instance of the Address object
        Address addr = new Address();

       //Add new values to each field
       addr.Street = "foo";
       addr.Apt = "foo"
       addr.City = "foo";
       addr.State = "foo";
       addr.Zip = "foo";
       //etc

       //Insert the new Address object
       db.Address.InsertOnSubmit(cust);
        //Sumbit changes to the database
        db.SubmitChanges(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything looks fine, what error/Exception are you getting?

Comment: Do you get a compile error ? What does it tell you ?

Comment: No exception at all.  VS won't even allow me to type "Address addr.." because it doesn't seem to recognize the Address class.

Comment: Actually if i just copy and paste what I have above is says "Unknown type 'Address'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken your `Address` is in a different namespace.

```
SBMData2.Address addr = new SBMData2.Address();
```

Either that or add a `using` statement at the top of you class.

```
using SBMData2;
```

Comment: Gosh that was it.  I was hesitant to post this question because I had a feeling I was overlooking something simple like that.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad I could help. please mark the question as closed. Thanks.

Comment: Will do.  I tried to close it already and got a message to that I can't close it for 5 mins.  Must be a new feature.